# Setting up Curl for Visual Studio 2017: NMAKE: fatal error U1073: don't know how to make '..\src\tool_hugehelp.c'

Tags: c++, visual-studio, curl

I'm currently trying to build curl for VS2017, when setting things up with x86 Native Tools Command Prompt, I run the command:

```
nmake /f Makefile.vc mode=static vc=15 debug=yes
```

When it gets to the part "Copying libs" it gives me the error:

```
NMAKE: fatal error U1073: don't know how to make '..\src\tool_hugehelp.c'
```

As well as another error below:

```
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX86\x86\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
```

Does anyone know why these errors would be occurring? Or how to resolve them?

Answer (score 9):

If the first answer did not clear things up(if though it is the right.)
Download the lib curl from Github.
Steps for building x64 Debug:

1. Open x64 Native Tools Command Prompt VS 2019
2. cd into the repo.
3. open the repo in file explorer and double click `buildconf.bat`
   file.
4. cd into \buildtools in x64 Native Tools Command Prompt VS
   2019
5. Type, set RTLIBCFG=static, Press enter.

6.Type, nmake /f Makefile.vc mode=static vc=16 debug=yes

- For Release
- Type, nmake /f Makefile.vc mode=static vc=16 debug=no

Comment: Summary: Run `buildconf.bat` to generate `..\src\tool_hugehelp.c`

Answer (score 3):

after download and unzip curl files , u find in Curl directory buildconf.bat , run them and u get tool_hugehelp.c for nmake

Comment: can you please contextualize ore your answer? provide some code example etc

Comment: after download and unzip curl files , u find in Curl directory buildconf.bat , run them and u get  tool_hugehelp.c for nmake